# Redux form - enableReinitialize override previous data and keepDirtyOnReinitialize doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I've created a Wizard contact form where at a certain step I've got a "Sign in button with Google", if the user signs in with Google then some of the CF's fields are filled out with the Google data (name, surname, email).

Everything works fine but I noticed that once the user signs in and the fields are filled out, the previous data of the form (the data I got in the previous steps) get lost and replaced completely with "name", "surname" and "email".

In order to solve this issue, I've tried to use "keepDirtyOnReinitialize" but nothing seems to change and I don't really know how to make it work at this point.

This is my code where I create the form and where I get the info from Redux store:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Info extends React.Component {
    renderError({ error, touched }) {
        if (touched && error) {
            return <div>{error}</div>
        }
    }

    renderInputField = ({ input, label, meta }) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <input {...input} type="text" placeholder={label} />
                {this.renderError(meta)}
            </div>
        );
    };

    onSubmit = (formValues) => {
        this.props.onSubmit(formValues)
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                    <div>
                        <Field
                            name="nome"
                            component={this.renderInputField}
                            label="Nome *"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Field
                            name="cognome"
                            component={this.renderInputField}
                            label="Cognome *"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Field
                            name="email"
                            component={this.renderInputField}
                            label="Email *"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Field
                            name="azienda"
                            component={this.renderInputField}
                            label="Azienda"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Field
                            name="citta"
                            component={this.renderInputField}
                            label="Città / CAP / Provincia"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button>Visualizza</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const validate = formValues => {
    const errors = {}

    if (!formValues.nome) {
        errors.nome = "Aggiungi il nome"
    }

    if (!formValues.cognome) {
        errors.cognome = "Aggiungi il cognome"
    }

    if (!formValues.email) {
        errors.email = "Aggiungi l'email"
    } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(formValues.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Email non valida'
    }

    return errors
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    let initValues

    if (state.auth.isSignedIn) {
        initValues = {
            nome: state.auth.userProfile.ofa,
            cognome: state.auth.userProfile.wea,
            email: state.auth.userProfile.U3
        }
    }

    return {
        userData: state.auth,
        initialValues: initValues
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({
    form: 'companyData',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    //forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
    enableReinitialize: true,
    keepDirtyOnReinitialize: false,
    validate
})(Info))
```

These are my data before I sign in:

[image]

And these are the data after I sign in with Google and I recover the data to fill out the fields

[image]

initialValues reset all the data and create these new three but according to the Redux form documentation I should be able to keep the previous data by using keepDirtyOnReinitialize, but it doesn't work.

My Redux Form version is: 8.1.0

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `let initValues = {}` does the trick. I am not sure why but here's a codesandbox, after 3 seconds the reinitialize gets emulated and the other fields are retained => https://codesandbox.io/s/y2kyo20vox